# Oracle job does not work properly

Tags: oracle, jobs, dbms-scheduler

I created jobs like this.

```
 DECLARE
      X NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      SYS.DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT
      ( job       => X 
       ,what      => 'PROCEDURE_CATCH;'
       ,next_date => to_date('16/05/2018 16:07:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
       ,interval  => 'SYSDATE + 1 / 24 / 12'
       ,no_parse  => FALSE
      );
      SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job Number is: ' || to_char(x));
    COMMIT;
    END;
    /
```

But after sometime maybe 10 20 minutes , I refreshed the job and I saw that Last date,this date, next date,this sec and next sec didn't change, they stayed as they were.
[image]

What is the problem here ?

Comment: "Next Date" is lower than current date. I think that is the reason. Try `next_date => SYSDATE`

Comment: It isnt becasue of that...

Comment: How long does the job run? More than 5 Minutes?

Comment: Do you get the same when select directly `select * from user_jobs;` instead of IDE?

Comment: Consider [SCHEDULER JOBS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm#ADMIN034). Interval would be `FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=5` Package [DBMS_JOB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/appendix_a.htm#ADMIN11002) is deprecated.

Comment: I get the same when I run the select. last date i last sec are empty fields.. 
I set interval every 5 minutes.

Comment: And what will i put in end_date in scheduler jobs statement .  I dont have end date of this job.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171239/discussion-between-civesuas-sine-and-wernfried-domscheit).